# df.append() not adding rows to dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm using a very simple piece of code and initializing a `pandas dataframe` with a single row and then adding other rows from a `list` named `itemsets_dct` and then `appending` them to the `dataframe`, using the following code:

```
finalResults = pd.DataFrame({'Concept1': itemsets_dct[0][0][0], 'Concept2': itemsets_dct[0][0][1], 'Concept3': itemsets_dct[0][0][2], 'Concept4': itemsets_dct[0][0][3], 'Count': itemsets_dct[0][1]}, index=[0])
for i in range(1,len(itemsets_dct)):
    tempResult = pd.DataFrame({'Concept1': itemsets_dct[i][0][0], 'Concept2': itemsets_dct[i][0][1], 'Concept3': itemsets_dct[i][0][2], 'Concept4': itemsets_dct[i][0][3], 'Count': itemsets_dct[i][1]}, index=[i])
    finalResults.append(tempResult)
```

when I run this code, it executes without any errors, but the `finalResults` variable only has 1 row, the row that I initialized.

Why is the code not `appending` rows to the `dataframe`?

Comment: `append` is not an inplace operation, so you need to reassign. i.e. `finalResults = finalResults.append(tempResult)`.

Comment: Can't imagine the sdolution would be so simple. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Also show the contents of *itemsets_dct* as there may be a preferred way to do this in one call instead of iteratively in loop.

Answer (score 1):

Consider not using an iterative `for` loop append but building a list of dictionaries that you then cast into a dataframe all in one call. Below hopefully recreates the outer structure of your nested list:

```
itemsets_dct = [[['check1', 'check2', 'check3', 'check4'], 3],
                [['check11', 'check22', 'check33', 'check44'], 3],
                [['check111', 'check222', 'check333', 'check444'], 3]]

dfDict = [{'Concept1': i[0][0],
           'Concept2': i[0][1],
           'Concept3': i[0][2],
           'Concept4': i[0][3],
           'Count': i[1]} for i in itemsets_dct]

finalresults = pd.DataFrame(dfDict)
print(finalresults)

#    Concept1  Concept2  Concept3  Concept4  Count
# 0    check1    check2    check3    check4      3
# 1   check11   check22   check33   check44      3
# 2  check111  check222  check333  check444      3
```